# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 334: character maps to <undefined> Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, unicode

При чтении ".jpg" файла возникла следующая ошибка:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 334: character maps to <undefined`>

Функция, где производится чтение:

```
def readFile(self, data_path):
        if self.mode == 'encode':
            input_file = open(data_path, 'r')
            data = input_file.read()
        else: 
            pass

        input_file.close()

        return data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.jpg` файл нужно читать в двоичном режиме:

```
with open(data_path, 'rb') as input_file:
                     ^^^^ двоичный режим
    data = input_file.read()
```

А в целом у вас непонятно, что будет при другом `mode`, код совсем тогда сломается.